# Hide the navigation bar in Android application for all UI elements

Tags: android, android-navigation

So a basic question, I call the following code in onResume of each Activity to hide the navigation bar in my android application (running on KitKat).

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
```

So my question is firstly, can I do this in one place for the entire application or do I need to call this in every Activity that I create?

Second question is, when I have a dialog or popup menu or some UI element that is superimposed above the current Activity layout the navigation bar appears again, how do I stop this from happening?

Comment: Have you tried what happens if you hide the navigation bar in one Activity, does the next Activity show the navigation bar?

Comment: @Christine it reappears, I have to do this in each activity which is not really a problem, just more an annoyance. The problem is when I have an alert dialog for example, it then makes the navigation bar reappear :/

Comment: There's no other place where you can set this, so you have your answer: you need to do it in every activity.